# How to assign a chrome tab to a variable by a given tab id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to assign a tab to a variable; but I failed. Here is my code:

```
var tab;
chrome.tabs.get(id, function(t) {
  tab = t;
  console.log("tab: " + tab); // here the printed result is right
});
console.log("(after assignment) tab: " + tab); // always get "undefined"
```

The code is simple but I don't know where the problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in asynchronous Chrome API calls, meaning that you don't receive response from them immediately. You can rewrite your code in this way for example:

```
var tab;
chrome.tabs.get(id, function(t) {
  tab = t;
  console.log("tab: " + tab); // here the printed result is right

  afterAssignment();
});

function afterAssignment() {
    console.log("(after assignment) tab: " + tab); // always get "undefined"

    //the rest of the code that needs to use tab var
}
```